# Appropriate usage of the word "legislate"

Tags: passive-voice, prepositional-phrases

Which of following sentences make sense better?

1. This law have been legislated **for regarding of** worker's rights
2. This law have been legislated **to regard** worker's rights

Comment: "This law" is singular, so it should be "this law *has*", not *have*.

Answer (score 1):

I would not call either of your sentences correct.

---

The first issue is that using *to legislate* with a law (or regulation or ordinance) as the subject doesn't make sense. Refer to this definition (from Oxford Dictionaries):

> [**legislate**](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/legislate) *Verb*
>
> **1** *[no object]* Make or enact laws:
>   *"they legislated against discrimination in the workplace"*
>
> **1.1** *[with object]* Bring about by making or enacting laws:
>   *"constitutional changes will be legislated"*

That is, the thing which *legislates* is the thing creating the law. This is usually a branch of government, typically a Parliament or Congress (the [*legislatures*](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/legislature)) – however, it is common for the executive, judiciary (court system), and councils to also legislate to an extent.

---

The second issue is that neither of your sentences correctly use a phrase of *regard*. In this case, the correct phrase is *with regard to*:

> [**with (or in) regard to**](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/with_(or_in)_regard_to) *Phrase*
>
> As concerns; with respect to.
>   *"he made inquiries with regard to Beth"*

---

If you wanted to refer to what a legislature has done, you would say:

> The Parliament **has legislated with regard to** workers' rights.

Meaning that the Parliament has made laws that relate to the rights of workers.

If you want to refer specifically to a law being passed, you might say:

> This law [**relating to**](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/relate) workers' rights **has been passed** by the
>   Parliament.
>
> This law **relating to** workers' rights **passed** on Monday.

A legislature generally makes laws by voting on them, and so this definition of *pass* is used:

> [**pass**](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/pass) *Verb*
>
> **6** *[with object]* (of a legislative or other official body) approve or
>   put into effect (a proposal or law) by voting on it.
>   *"the bill was passed despite fierce opposition"*
>
> **6.1** *[no object]* (of a proposal or law) be examined and approved by
>   (a legislative body or process)
>   *"the bill passed by 164 votes to 107"*

Some legislatures might use their own terminology or jargon, but the verb *to pass* will be understood to mean the law was accepted by the legislature. Depending on how far you're going into the process, you might also use [*to promulgate*](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/promulgate) (for putting the law into effect) or [*come into force*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coming_into_force) (of a law, to start having legal force).

Comment: But I saw a sentence in dictionary which used law as a object: " the parliment legislates laws and the government executes them"

Comment: @Hamid: I haven't seen that usage before, and it doesn't line up with the dictionary definitions I've provided. Can you provide a link or reference to where you saw that sentence?